# Trying to combine a float operand and a degree symbol into the same variable

Tags: python

All i am trying to do is add a degree symbol ("\N{degree sign}") to a float operand in python but i get the error "unsupported operand types for +" i have tried saving it as a string and an integer but it didnt work either

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.Please read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to find out how to get the best answers to your questions.

Comment: You have to convert the float to a string so you can concatenate them.

Comment: Or you can use a string formatting function.